# Unable to run flutter command on VS code terminal

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, command

as You can see each time i run commands on the terminal they just doesnt work
when i run flutter doctor using the command palette everything is installed fine
[click to see photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrDpw.png)

Comment: Do not upload code as an image.

Comment: read the problem 
thats not a code issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i didnt add the flutter path in the "environment variables for your account" doing so solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You just do not write the commands correctly, the error says that you have typed extra unwanted characters such as `+` sign, so read the error again and try to copy-paste the following command to the VS Code Terminal and see if it worked or not:

```
flutter doctor
```

Comment: still same problem

Comment: Can you share me a video while you are executing the commands? you can use `loom` to quickly record and upload the video.

Comment: thank you , i have found the solution

Comment: Great, kindly add your solution as an answer and accept to let people know the solution in the future.